# Bind functions events to a checkbox/label on change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

I am trying to add some functionality to the following component, basically when the user clicks on the parent "li label checkbox" this should check/unchecked the > "ul li label checkboxes", the problem is that I am using the label to trigger show/hide the next "ul" and can't bind another function, the ideal escenario will be as follow:

click on li label {element} > slidedown the next ul
click on li label {Checkbox} > check/uncheck the next ul checkboxes childs

I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/creativestudio/cxnu4c0b/) at this point the html markup cannot be changed :/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      function dropdown() {
        $("#sidebarNav label").not("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function (e) {
          if (jQuery(this).parent().has("ul")) {
            e.preventDefault();
          }      

          $(this).next('ul').slideToggle('fast');
          $(this).find('i').toggleClass('ion-plus ion-minus');

          //console.log(this);

          if (jQuery(this).hasClass('has-dropdown')) {
            $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
            //var item = $(this).find('input');
            //console.log(item);
          }

          var checkbox = $(this).find('input').is(":checked");
          //console.log(checkbox);
          if(checkbox) {
              //console.log("checked.");
          } else {
              //console.log("unchecked.");
          }

        });


      } dropdown();

      $("#checkAll").change(function () {
        $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
      });

    });
```

Comment: I added styles to the menu https://jsfiddle.net/creativestudio/cxnu4c0b/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function dropdown() {
    $("#sidebarNav li").has("ul").find(' > label input').on('change', function (e) {
        var $ul = $(this).parent().next();
        $ul.slideToggle('fast');
        $ul.find('input').prop('checked', this.checked);
        $(this).prev('i').add($ul.find('i')).toggleClass('ion-plus', this.checked).toggleClass('ion-minus', !this.checked);
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nvg3j7mz/)

Comment: Hello @arun the function looks much better and clean, I have a question.. if the child ul are not visible, basically the menus are not collapsed like the following https://jsfiddle.net/creativestudio/nvg3j7mz/3/ is there any way to prevent the child ul's to collapse up when clicking only on the checkbox?

Comment: @user1547007 sorry I didn't get you - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nvg3j7mz/5/

Comment: Hi @Arun, the first time you click on the parent should collapse the panel & toggle left icon from (+-) & leave the checkbox checked, once the dropdown is visible and if has childs, user can check/uncheck clicking only on the checkbox elem (parent li checkbox checks/unchecks child checkboxes or user can do it individually) but this should not collapse the panel, if the user clicks on the label block but not the check element, this collapses the dropdown & toggles +- class of left icon,does it make sense? I updated the jsfiddle styles  https://jsfiddle.net/creativestudio/ywpL7md3/

Comment: I sent the invite @arun

Comment: This is the original code with styles, the missing function was when clicking  only the checkbox to check/uncheck individually and per group checkboxes https://jsfiddle.net/creativestudio/cxnu4c0b/2/

Comment: little busy now... will try to check it little later